# How to store a MAC address field in a django model?

Tags: django, django-models

What is the best type to use for a **MAC8 address** field in a django **model**?

For IP, I'm using models.GenericIPAddressField(), but there is no models.MacAddr8()

Currently I'm using models.TextField()

Answer (score 3):

I would personally stick to `models.CharField()`, and then use a custom model method to convert it if need be, but there is a package that seems to do this more professionally called [django-macaddress.](https://github.com/django-macaddress/django-macaddress)